# Can't re-format disk after Linux install

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

So,
The story goes,

1. Having a fun time playing with Linux
2. Format a drive in EXT4 I think it was
3. Decide I'm not playing with Linux today because I need that drive for other things now
4. Plug a windows installer USB into machine
5. Can't install onto that drive

So now I went ah ok I'll go fix it with diskpart in the installer USB!
Drive doesn't show up on '**list disk**' command

I plugged it into another machine, not detected in disk management or diskpart,
but it is detected in BIOS and Device Manager

**TL;DR**: installed linux onto HDD, want to reformat but it's not showing in disk management or diskpart, it does show in BIOS and Device manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues to consider.

1. The partition is marked as a "type", they are not generic. This is like a magic number. So you need to actually delete the partition and recreate it.
2. The filesystem is created within the partition, and can sometimes be smaller, especially if the partition has been stretched.

Two ways to fix quickly.  The first is to zero the first cluster, and can be very risky if you are confused as to the disk you are working with and it is not the only disk.

The second is to boot a Linux Live distribution, run GPARTED, and delete the partition. Windows will cope with missing partitions better than partitions of the wrong type. Also delete any Linux Swap partition if it exists, it may not.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem a while ago. I ended up using a Linux live cd to format the drive to something Windows can handle, and afterwards used the windows installer. Hopefully this method works for you too.

On some USB drives I've been lucky to change the format with Windows diskpart, but not with that particular HDD. No clue why.